# Select region between empty lines

Tags: selection, paragraphs

If I use `(thing-at-point 'paragraph)` (or `mark-paragraph`, for that matter), the selection isn't necessarily aware only about the empty lines. Especially, with lists and code blocks in org-mode.

So, I need a function which returns the bounds which include everything between surrounding blank lines. How would I do that?

**EDIT**

So, to clarify, if I do `(thing-at-point 'paragraph)` here:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
x = 1
y = 2
#+END_SRC
```

I get:

```
"x = 1
y = 2
#+END_SRC" <font info>
```

Comment: Can you clarify? Eg give an example where this does not do what you want.

Comment: @JeanPierre sure, edited the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that returns the text between two surrounding blank lines:

```el
(defun region-between-surrounding-blank-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg nil) (end nil))
    (save-excursion
      (re-search-backward (rx bol (* blank) eol))
      (setq beg (point))
      (forward-char)
      (re-search-forward (rx bol (* blank) eol))
      (setq end (- (point) 1)))
    (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))
```

Edit: Executing the function above raises an error if there are no two blank lines in the buffer. Here is an alternative version where text is selected from the beginning/end of the buffer if there are no blank line above/below the current position:

```el
(defun region-between-surrounding-blank-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg nil) (end nil))
    (save-excursion
      (if (re-search-backward (rx bol (* blank) eol) nil t nil)
        (setq beg (point))
        (setq beg (point-min)))
      (forward-char)
      (if (re-search-forward (rx bol (* blank) eol) nil t nil)
        (setq end (- (point) 1))
        (setq end (point-max))))
    (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully [StarBug](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/23522/starbug) gave you [an answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50711/2370) to your literal question about stuff between newlines.

Your clarification suggests that you are actually looking for `org-element-context`.

That function gives you the org element at point which can be a source block.

The returned element has properties like its bounds (`:begin` and `:end`) and its contents (`:value`).

The following Elisp code makes `(thing-at-point 'org-src-block)` work. You can use that instead of `(thing-at-point 'paragraph)` if you are actually looking for the source block.

```el
(defun org-src-block-at-point ()
  "Return source block at point as string."
  (let ((el (org-element-context)))
    (when (eq (org-element-type el) 'src-block)
      (buffer-substring-no-properties
       (org-element-property :begin el)
       (save-excursion
     (goto-char (org-element-property :end el))
     (skip-chars-backward "\n[:space:]")
     (point))))))

;; Enable (thing-at-point 'org-src-block):
(put 'org-src-block 'thing-at-point #'org-src-block-at-point)
```

Comment: This will come in handy, thank you!